# How to use SCSS with existing site

Tags: css, sass

I have a question about SCSS. I am new at this, so if I'm not providing enough information please let me know so that I can update my question.

I am currently working on a Wordpress installation that has an SCSS directory, with all of the various .scss files.

I tried editing the files directly, and came across a lot of issues. I did some research, and it looks like the scss needs to be compiled into css so that the site can read it. Issue is, no matter how I try, it just simply doesn't work. The site styles break, and the updated code won't work. I know I can change the css directly, but I understand that if the scss is recompiled it will remove my direct css changes.

Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: You can use a gem to do so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427849/how-to-watch-changes-in-whole-directory-folder-containing-many-sass-files/26675999#26675999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any way to compile the SASS to CSS then an easy way to translate your code is by using [sassmeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/).