# What is the best way to use SASS inside a Blazor Web Assembly project?

Tags: asp.net-core, sass, blazor

What is the best way to use SASS with Client side blazor. I looked into the this

https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler

But it looks like works only with Visual Studio. I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: did my answer help you at all? My LibSassBuilder is now available as a global tool as well.

Comment: @JvR I have installed libsassbuilder - it does compile the sass into css as expected but it is not getting applied in my blazor project. I wonder - does it run before the build? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0  " integrating CSS preprocessors is seamless as long as preprocessor compilation occurs before Blazor rewrites the CSS selectors during the build process." could this be an issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#css-preprocessor-support), you can use the [Delegate.SassBuilder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Delegate.SassBuilder) package to help you compile `sass/scss` files to `css`.

It works pretty well, and very easy to install with no configuration required.

**NOTE**

For newer Sass build requirements - I've created this [LibSassBuilder](https://github.com/johan-v-r/LibSassBuilder)

Comment: Delegate.SassBuilder works in MVC projects :)

Comment: As the `Delegate.SassBuilder` uses `.exe` file this does not work on linux distros. The other answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using sass directly from the command line.* Note that:

> Dart Sass is the primary implementation of Sass

and it can be installed and used globally as a CLI tool, no npm project or pipeline required is the key.

You can [install `sass`](https://sass-lang.com/install) via `choco`:

```
choco install sass
```

Or with with `npm`:

```
npm install -g sass
```

Then you can right click on `wwwroot` and select `Open in terminal` and build and watch in native ways enabled by sass. To [watch all see the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23114536/264031) for instance:

```
sass --watch .:.
```

[image]

- (A bit begrudgingly, but other solutions, like building on every build, has big downsides. Like it building sass resources on every build: That's really wasteful when you've not been messing with your styles ... Or take the fact, in my case right now, that neither the `WebCompiler` extension nor `LibSassBuilder` as mentioned above seem to work on this preview version of Visual Studio.)

Comment: Very helpful answer. And do you know any way to bind this routine to `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch` command? For example like scripts in `package.json` when using npm.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a simple console application, that can compile sass files to css with RCL support in Blazor WASM.

You can add your sass files into the `wwwroot` of RCL and write "_content/MyLibrary/sass.scss" in `@use` or `@import` at the Blazor Client. Watch mode also supported.

You can find the tool on [github](https://github.com/MONQDL/DartSassBuildWatcherTool).

Comment: Great!, this is exactly what I need to share the scss variables using RCL! Thank you!